# Why do I get a "only one runtime can be active" error when I've only specified one runtime for sqlx and axum-database-sessions?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx, rust-axum

From Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "sitegen"
version = "0.2.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum_database_sessions = { version = "5.0", features = [ "mysql-native"] }
sqlx = { version = "0.6", features = ["runtime-tokio-rustls", "mysql"] }
tokio = { version = "1.0", features = ["full"] }
```

Compile Error:

```
error: only one of ['runtime-actix-native-tls', 'runtime-async-std-native-tls', 'runtime-tokio-native-tls', 'runtime-actix-rustls', 'runtime-async-std-rustls', 'runtime-tokio-rustls'] can be enabled
 --> /home/dsrich/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sqlx-rt-0.6.2/src/lib.rs:23:1
  |
23 | / compile_error!(
24 | |     "only one of ['runtime-actix-native-tls', 'runtime-async-std-native-tls', \
25 | |      'runtime-tokio-native-tls', 'runtime-actix-rustls', 'runtime-async-std-rustls', \
26 | |      'runtime-tokio-rustls'] can be enabled"
27 | | );
  | |_^

error: could not compile `sqlx-rt` due to previous error
```

I am using the latest rust x86-64 on linux, MySQL, and having rustls present in Cargo.toml or not makes no difference. Any suggestions? Just makes no sense to me...

Just trying to compile it to start using it with axum-sessions

Comment: Thanks, cafce25 for the help. I am still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default features of `axum_database_session` is `["postgres-rustls"]` therefore if you want to use `*-native` you have to disable default features:

```ini
axum_database_sessions = { version = "5.0", default-features = false, features = ["mysql-native"] }
```

but since you're explicitly including `rustls` in your dependency on `sqlx` you probably just want to use `mysql-rustls` instead, still without the default features because you're using MySQL instead of PostgreSQL:

```ini
axum_database_sessions = { version = "5.0", default-features = false, features = ["mysql-rustls"] }
```

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer with what you probably want instead `mysql-rustls` since you specified `runtime-tokio-rustls` on `sqlx`